# Ckeditor 4.10 FULL package not displaying color buttons

Tags: ckeditor, colordialog

I have upgraded from ckeditor version 4.6.2 full package to 4.10 full package and the color buttons are not appearing.

Here is my toolbar config:

```
config.toolbar = [
    { name: 'clipboard', items: ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'] },
    { name: 'editing', items: ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt'] },
    { name: 'tools', items: ['ShowBlocks'] },
    { name: 'links', items: ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'] },
    { name: 'insert', items: ['Image', 'Table', 'SpecialChar', 'Iframe'] },
    { name: 'document', items: ['Source'] },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'CopyFormatting', 'RemoveFormat'] },
    { name: 'colors', items: ['TextColor', 'BGColor'] },
    { name: 'styles', items: ['Format', 'Font', 'FontSize'] },
    { name: 'paragraph', items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList',  '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl', ] },
];
```

I am not getting any errors, is there a work around for this? This is a critical plugin for our platform.

Comment: Could you simply make sure that you have downloaded full package from here https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/download/ (don't check the Easy Image checkbox if you don't plan to use CKSource Cloud Services) and that you have cleared your browser's cache according to https://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser%27s-Cache? If you don't have any non-standard configuration (e.g. you don't allow spans) then it should work out of the box.

Comment: You could also check the Toolbar Configurator - https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_toolbar.html (available in your samples folder) to make sure that configuration is correct however if it was working in 4.6.2 it should work in 4.10.0

Comment: Did you figure this out?